# Jsprit outputing and Saving variables

Tags: java, xml, jsprit

Is there a way to obtain the output/store results in variables other than outputting solutions to an xml file using **vrpxmlwriter**?

I tried to get the results with dom parser, xpath and family and can proudly say that I made a complete mess!! Common Jsprit team you've made this beautiful piece of art, why couldn't you provide us with functions like `bestSolution.getAllVehicles()` ??

If i'm wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging only from the source code, shouldn't you be able to easily extract all the vehicles from the `bestSolution` instance?

Assuming `bestSolution` is of type `VehicleRoutingProblemSolution`, I'd expect something like this to work:

```
Collection<VehicleRoute> routes = bestSolution.getRoutes();
Set<Vehicle> allVehicles = routes
    .stream()
    .map(VehicleRoute::getVehicle)
    .collect(Collectors::toSet());
```

It seems like `VehicleRoutingProblemSolution` contains a lot of information and you are inetersted in a specific projection/subset of this information. Since there are clearly a lot of such subsets, I think it quite reasonable that the API does not provide all of them.

Comment: what! O.o it does exist? holy mother of god !  and is there a function to get the activity with the corresponding vehicles? could you provide a link  from where you are getting these info ? thanks

Comment: @MattieuKevin [Source code of jsprit](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/blob/7590be97948da47eefed61413c27f2a70b6ff434/jsprit-core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/jsprit/core/problem/solution/route/VehicleRoute.java).